# type annotations needed for a simple trait

Tags: rust

The following very simple state machine I designed is giving me errors about type annotation

```
struct RtspMachine<S> {
    s: S
}

impl<S> RtspMachine<S> {
    pub fn new(s: S) -> Self {
        RtspMachine::<S>{s:s}
    }
}

struct Init {

}

struct Ready {

}

struct Playing {

}

struct Recording{

}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Response {
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Event{
    Play(Response),
    Setup(Response),
    Pause(Response),
    Teardown(Response),
    Record(Response)
}

enum RtspMachineWrapper {
    Init(RtspMachine<Init>),
    Ready(RtspMachine<Ready>),
    Playing(RtspMachine<Playing>),
    Recording(RtspMachine<Recording>),
}

struct Factory {
    rtsp_machine_wrapper: RtspMachineWrapper,
}


impl Factory {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Factory {
            rtsp_machine_wrapper: RtspMachineWrapper::Init(RtspMachine::new(Init{})),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum EventError {
    EventNotImplemented,
    ImpossibleTransition
}

impl RtspMachineWrapper {
    fn event(mut self, event: &Event) -> std::result::Result<Self, EventError> {
        match self {
            RtspMachineWrapper::Init(rtsp_machine) => {
                StateChange::from(rtsp_machine, event)
            },
            RtspMachineWrapper::Ready(rtsp_machine) => {
                StateChange::from(rtsp_machine, event)
            },
            RtspMachineWrapper::Playing(rtsp_machine) => {
                StateChange::from(rtsp_machine, event)
            },
            RtspMachineWrapper::Recording(val) => {
                Err(EventError::EventNotImplemented)
            },
        }
    }
}

trait StateChange<T> where Self: Sized {
    fn from(t: T, event: &Event) -> std::result::Result<RtspMachineWrapper, EventError>;
}

impl StateChange<RtspMachine<Init>> for RtspMachine::<Ready> {
    fn from(init: RtspMachine<Init>, event: &Event)  -> std::result::Result<RtspMachineWrapper, EventError>{
        match event {
            Event::Play(response) => Err(EventError::ImpossibleTransition),
            //Event::Setup(response) => ,
            Event::Pause(response) => Err(EventError::ImpossibleTransition),
            //Event::Teardown(response) => ,
            Event::Record(response) => Err(EventError::EventNotImplemented)
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/lib.rs:70:17
   |
70 |                 StateChange::from(rtsp_machine, event)
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
...
86 |     fn from(t: T, event: &Event) -> std::result::Result<RtspMachineWrapper, EventError>;
   |     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ required by `StateChange::from`
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: StateChange<RtspMachine<Init>>`
```

I don't know why, since `rtsp_machine` and `event` both have a clear type because they come from a `match`. Also, what does the `_` means in `_: StateChange<RtspMachine<Init>>`?

I don't see any reason why a specific type must be annotated

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b599858f69a0210a4eaf9349e9827297)

Comment: The annotation is needed to define the type to use that implements `StateChange<RtspMachine<Init>>`. You have one for `RtspMachine<Ready>` but traits can be implemented for many types and the compiler won't guess for you.

Comment: @kmdreko but `match self {
            RtspMachineWrapper::Init(rtsp_machine) => {` narrows down `rtsp_machine` to `RtspMachine<Init>`, therefore calling `StateChange::from(rtsp_machine, event)` should be the same as `StateChange::<RtspMachine<Init>>::from::(rtsp_machine, event)`

Comment: [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1eddd6c28c15c8e38e2c8e0b48a0919e) I've implemented `StateChange<RtspMachine<Init>>` for both `RtspMachine<Ready>` and `RtspMachine<Playing>`, which one should the compiler choose?